# XSL-FO use attributes dynamically

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

**Attributes:**

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="dark-red">
    <xsl:attribute name="color">red</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

**Template:**

```
<xsl:template name="myTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="style">dark-red</xsl:param>
    <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="{$style}">
        <fo:block>Not Red</fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
</xsl:template>
```

However when not using a variable / parameter it seems to work:

```
<xsl:template name="myTemplate">
    <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="dark-red">
        <fo:block>Red</fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there any particular reason for this or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use dynamic values in `xsl:use-attribute-sets`. You would have to create required attributes in the elements.